# How to do simple cross field validation in Angular 2 form to pass validation if one of the control in group has value?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

This is so commonly used, there must be a simple way to approach this! So here is the situation. I have a form group:

```
  <ion-item-group formGroupName="alternativeRevenue">
    <ion-item-divider color="primary" text-wrap sticky>Alternative revenue </ion-item-divider>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Branded content</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle formControlName="brandedContent"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item text-wrap *ngIf="businessFoundationsForm.get('alternativeRevenue.brandedContent').value">
      <ion-label floating>you want to work with?</ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="typesOfBrands"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Merchandise</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle formControlName="merchandise"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item text-wrap *ngIf="businessFoundationsForm.get('alternativeRevenue.merchandise').value">
      <ion-label floating>What types of brands</ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="typeOfMerchandise"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Podcasts</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle formControlName="podcasts"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item text-wrap *ngIf="businessFoundationsForm.get('alternativeRevenue.podcasts').value">
      <ion-label floating>Brainstorm topic ideas </ion-label>
      <ion-textarea fz-elastic formControlName="podcastIdeas"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Tours</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle formControlName="tours"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item text-wrap *ngIf="businessFoundationsForm.get('alternativeRevenue.tours').value">
      <ion-label floating>Brainstorm tour </ion-label>
      <ion-textarea fz-elastic formControlName="tourIdeas"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Deals</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle formControlName="licensingDeals"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item text-wrap *ngIf="businessFoundationsForm.get('alternativeRevenue.licensingDeals').value">
      <ion-label floating>Two ideas for licensing</ion-label>
      <ion-textarea fz-elastic formControlName="licensingIdeas"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-item-group>
```

And here is the Form group in component:

```
   alternativeRevenue: this.fb.group({
    brandedContent: [false],
    typesOfBrands: [null],
    merchandise: [false],
    typeOfMerchandise: [null],
    podcasts: [false],
    podcastIdeas: [null],
    tours: [false],
    tourIdeas: [null],
    licensingDeals: [false],
    licensingIdeas: [null]
  }, {validator: alternativeRevenueGroupValidator})
```

My goal is, if one of the select / ion-toggle is true, and the associated input filed is NOT empty and has min length of more than 10, the from group is validated. If I add the [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)] to all the field, it will require all the field to be filled before the form group to be validated. I just want ONE of them to be validate and then the whole group is validate. How can I do that?

UPDATE: here is the alternativeRevenueGroupValidator.

```
        function alternativeRevenueGroupValidator(c: AbstractControl) {
          let brandedContent = c.get('brandedContent');
          let typesOfBrands = c.get('typesOfBrands');
          let merchandise = c.get('merchandise');
          let typeOfMerchandise = c.get('typeOfMerchandise');
          let podcasts = c.get('podcasts');
          let podcastIdeas = c.get('podcastIdeas');
          let tours = c.get('tours');
          let tourIdeas = c.get('tourIdeas');
          let licensingDeals = c.get('licensingDeals');
          let licensingIdeas = c.get('licensingIdeas');

          if (brandedContent || merchandise || podcasts|| tours || licensingDeals) {
            if (typesOfBrands.value || typeOfMerchandise.value || podcastIdeas.value || tourIdeas.value || licensingIdeas.value) {
              return null;
            }
          }

          return {'GroupNoValue': true};
        }
```

As you see it is VERY UGLY. And it can ONLY validate if the input field has value or not. I can not value the min or max length or use library like this [enter link description here](https://github.com/yuyang041060120/ng2-validation)

Comment: It looks like you already might have it: can you post the code for `alternativeRevenueGroupValidator`

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36851837/angular-2-combined-form-validation . You can call `control.setErrors(null)` to clear the errors of a control once you've determined that the group validator takes precedence - meaning, you can have the validators on the individual controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to the `FormGroup` constructor lets you define a custom group validator.

Within the group validator, determine if the conditions are satisfied for a valid form (i.e. at least one input field is non-empty, and has a field length greater than 10).  If the form is valid, clear the individual errors by calling `control.setErrors(null)`. Otherwise, return a custom error object: `{ 'atLeastOneInputFieldMustBeValid': true }` so you can bind to it later.

```
    function alternativeRevenueGroupValidator(c: FormGroup) {
      let brandedContent = c.get('brandedContent');
      let typesOfBrands = c.get('typesOfBrands');
      let merchandise = c.get('merchandise');
      let typeOfMerchandise = c.get('typeOfMerchandise');
      let podcasts = c.get('podcasts');
      let podcastIdeas = c.get('podcastIdeas');
      let tours = c.get('tours');
      let tourIdeas = c.get('tourIdeas');
      let licensingDeals = c.get('licensingDeals');
      let licensingIdeas = c.get('licensingIdeas');

      if (brandedContent.valid || 
          merchandise.valid || 
          podcasts.valid || 
          tours.valid || 
          licensingDeals.valid ||
          typesOfBrands.valid ||
          typesOfMerchandise.valid || 
          postcastIdeas.valid ||
          tourIdeas.valid ||
          licensingIdeas.valid) {

          brandedContent.setErrors(null);
          merchandise.setErrors(null);
          podcasts.setErrors(null);
          tours.setErrors(null);
          licensingDeals.setErrors(null);
          typesOfBrands.setErrors(null);
          typesOfMerchandise.setErrors(null);
          postcastIdeas.setErrors(null);
          tourIdeas.setErrors(null);
          licensingIdeas.setErrors(null);
          return null;
        }
      }

      return {'GroupNoValue': true};
    }
```

Within the group validator function, you have the flexibility to inspect the validation flags of any control within the group, set the error object of any one of the controls, and finally you can return any validation object with any number of validation flags set.

If you require at least two of the fields to be required, and greater than 10 charaters, you might do something like this:

```
function alternativeRevenueGroupValidator(c: FormGroup) {
      var validCtls = c.controls.filter(c=> c.valid);
      if (validCtls.length >= 2) {
           c.controls.forEach((t)=> t.setErrors(null));
           return null;
      }
      return {'GroupNoTwoValues': true};
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated my questions to show my custom group validator. It is very messy and it can only do empty or not validation. I don't know how to do max / min length validator using Angular 2 prebuild validator. I don't know how to write my own...

Comment: Also, instead of 1 is ture and 1 is not NULL, what about if I want to make 2 are ture and 2 releated input box is not NULL?

Comment: There's a lot of flexibility in the group validator. You can return a key/value dictionary indicating which errors you want, and you can `setErrors(null)` to clear any errors on individual controls.  I agree, not pretty, but it works.

Comment: Looking at your update, so am I adding all the individual validator back to the group initialization like so: typesOfBrands: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]], and use your code just to see if one of them validate and set every individual errors to null? Also, if I require TWO of them be true and the TWO associated input filed not NULL and has min 10 character? Just to be clear the association, like brandedContent: [false] and  typesOfBrands: [null] is together. I need to validate first if the first one true and then validate the second. And since there are 4 pairs.

Comment: I want to custom validator see any 2 out of 4 are validated. Thanks!

Comment: Your group validator function will be complex, but it can be done.

Comment: Could you help me out on how? I have no clue....Thank BTW for all the helps so far

Comment: Wow, the second update answer is SOOOO MUCH clearer. I can filter them. The filter and loop tho the controls as an object array make things so much better. Great answer thank you so much!!