# How to make multiple validation on field in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am building a model driven form in angular 2 and i want a specific field to have a range validation between 1-1000 and can also have values of 2000 and 2001,

I tried to put it in compose:

```html
this.configForm.controls["field"].setValidators(Validators.compose([Validators.required,CustomValidators.equal(2000),CustomValidators.equal(2001), CustomValidators.range([1,1000])]));
```

But it didn't work..

How to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: is this a _reactive form_?

Comment: yes indeed it is

Answer (score 1):

If you are using FormBuilder, then consider implementing a group validator that validates a group of controls rather than individual ones:

[How to do simple cross field validation in Angular 2 form to pass validation if one of the control in group has value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591609/how-to-do-simple-cross-field-validation-in-angular-2-form-to-pass-validation-if/42592008?noredirect=1#comment72329124_42592008)

The second argument to FormBuilder's  `group` method allows you to specify a group validator:

```
 this.fb.group({
     field1: [''],
     field2: [''],
     }, 
     {
         validator: (c:FormGroup) => {
              return {'whateveryouwant': true};
         }
     }
 );
```

If you need to clear the fields validation flags:

```
let field1 = c.get('field1');
field1.setErrors(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [FormControl](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html) API,
there is no `setValidators()` function.

You may have to add new control:

```
this.configForm.controls["field"] = new FormControl('',Validators.compose([
      Validators.required,CustomValidators.equal(2000),
      CustomValidators.equal(2001), 
      CustomValidators.range([1,1000])]
      ));
```

Comment: hi, still not working , only if I remove the 2 equals the range take effect, I'm guessing it is not an OR connection, thanks