# Combining result (ORing) of 2 validators in Angular and using it as single validating factor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, validation, formbuilder

I want to get a validation result on a form field by ORing the 2 validation results

e.g.

```
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
username: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern(USERNAME_REGEX) || Validators.email]],
    });
```

Is something like this possible?

Constraints: **THE USERNAME SHOULD BE EITHER AN EMAIL ADDRESS OR SHOULD BE A VALID USERNAME WHICH MATCHES TO THE PATTERN OF USERNAME'S REGEX**

I want to use angular's inbuilt email validators' output and the output of a custom made regex pattern to identify whether the field is valid or not.

PS: I have refered this post -> [Angular 2 combined form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36851837/angular-2-combined-form-validation) but it does not match my condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your own validator function.

```js
private loginNameValidator = (): ValidatorFn => {
    const userNameValidator = Validators.pattern(USERNAME_REGEX);

    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
        const userNameInvalid = userNameValidator(control);
        if (!userNameInvalid) {
            return null;
        }

        const emailInvalid = Validators.email(control);
        if (!emailInvalid) {
            return null;
        }

        return { loginNameInvalid: true };
    };
};
```

Use it

```js
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    username: ['', [Validators.required, this.loginNameValidator()]],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no in built function which meets your requirements.

You will have to implement a custom validator for this.

```
public userNameOrEmailValidator(): ValidatorFn => {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const userNameRegex = // TODO: define username regex here.
    const emailRegex = // TODO: define email regex here.
    const isValid = userNameRegex.test(control.value) || emailRegex .test(control.value);
    return !isValid? {inValidUserName: true} : null;
  };
}
```

Call it like this:

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    username: ['', [Validators.required, userNameOrEmailValidator()]],
});
```

Comment: I used the custom email regex before but the requirement is that the email should be handled by inbuild typescript validator i.e. ```Validators.email```

Is there any other way to do it using regex for username and validators.email for email and then combining their results

Comment: you can use Validators.email and Validators.patern in your custom validator